# Regex Removing all non-digits and first char if it equals zero.

Tags: regex

I know this: `myString.replace(/\D/g,'')` replaces all non digits in myString. But if I also want to remove the first character only if it is equal to zero (0). Can I write this in one replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^0|\D
```

THis should do it.Try this.

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/28

```
1st Alternative: ^0

^ assert position at start of a line
0 matches the character 0 literally

2nd Alternative: \D

\D match any character that's not a digit [^0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an alteranation operator `|`.

```
myString.replace(/^0|\D/g,'')
```

`^` anchor asserts that we are at the start.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the below using pipeline operator, which means *or.* The Anchor `^` means start of the String.

```
myString = myString.replace(/^0|\D/g, "");
```